# Library Package Manager menu options not working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

The Library Package Manager menu options do not work when I click on the in Visual Studio 2012. Everything works fine in Visual Studio 2010. I have not been able to find an answer by searching online. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the NuGet Package and I get the message that it was installed sucessfully. When I opened Visual Studion 2012 a few days ago, I did get a message that there was a problem and something was written to a file but I accidently clicked on do not show again and canot find where the message was written.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have this same problem. Any solutions:??

Answer (score 0):

On the top right of Visual studio 2012, there is a search box. Search there for Console. First result will be Nuget Package Manager Console

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and nothing happens just like selecting the menu items. It just doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem.just go tools->extention and updates and uninstall nuget manager. then restart visual studio and install nuget and restart visual studio.then find your packages via nuget.